# jquery mask input s not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mask

Can anyone help for this?

```
    $("#mainForm").validate({
    rules: {
        mytxtName:{required:true},
        txtPhone:{required:true}
    }               
});
    $("#txtPhoneID").mask("999-999-9999");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ssthil/RjE8s/3/

Comment: If im right `mask` function will come as a plugin..you are not included that in your fiddle

Comment: @ubercoouk I added in the fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/ssthil/RjE8s/2/jquery.maskedinput-1.3.min.js)

Comment: @ubercooluk Thanks for your observation...

Comment: @ubercooluk I added now(http://cloud.github.com/downloads/digitalBush/jquery.maskedinput/jquery.maskedinput-1.3.min.js)...here I have one question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mask` method is not part of jQuery itself, it is comes with plugin.

Look at my code: http://jsfiddle.net/RjE8s/4/

Comment: @Danil Here I have one question. If i enter less than 10 digit, then entered data should n't clear instead of clear. Is it possible? Please help on this